# How to make handle asynchronous functionality of node js to synchronous in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous, aws-lib

In node js I have a aws API call within for loop .

```
var prodAdvOptions = {
        host : "webservices.amazon.in",
        region : "IN",
        version : "2013-08-01",
        path : "/onca/xml"
    };
    prodAdv = aws.createProdAdvClient(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKey, awsAssociateTag, prodAdvOptions);
    var n=100//Just for test
    for (var i = 0; i <=n; i++) {
        prodAdv.call("ItemSearch", {
            SearchIndex : "All",
            Keywords : "health,fitness,baby care,beauty",
            ResponseGroup : 'Images,ItemAttributes,Offers,Reviews',
            Availability : 'Available',
            ItemPage : 1

        }, function(err, result) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

Expected result is, after first result returns value, the second call request should go. But here the request/response were running asynchronously.How to make the next result wait until previous call returns response. Its okay even if it is slow.

Comment: Async module https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback

Comment: @RajPowar Thanks for your quick response. My next doubt is how to implement for loop within asyn.series to run make multiple functions.

Comment: You don't make it synchronous. You use a library or data structure that simplifies executing it in sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use async.whilst() as your **for** loop.  Something like this:

```
var async = require('async');

var prodAdvOptions = {
    host : "webservices.amazon.in",
    region : "IN",
    version : "2013-08-01",
    path : "/onca/xml"
};
var prodAdv = aws.createProdAdvClient(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKey, awsAssociateTag, prodAdvOptions);

var n=100;//Just for test
var i = 0;  // part 1 of for loop (var i = 0)
async.whilst(
    function () { return i <= n; },  // part 2 of for loop (i <=n)
    function (callback) {
        prodAdv.call("ItemSearch", {
            SearchIndex : "All",
            Keywords : "health,fitness,baby care,beauty",
            ResponseGroup : 'Images,ItemAttributes,Offers,Reviews',
            Availability : 'Available',
            ItemPage : 1
        }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
            i++;          // part 3 of for loop (i++)
            callback();
        });
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('done with all items from 0 - 100');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use promises instead of callbacks you can simply use recursion to achieve synchronization without the need of any external library to define the flow of the code execution.

You can do that with callbacks to  but the code will look horrible.